# How to add message to state in OpenERP

Tags: python, notifications, odoo

I have a very simple question. How to add own message to state on status bar?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to change the label of certain states for certain objects? (like draft, open, closed, cancelled?)

Comment: Sorry for poor English. Bottom of window, there's a state label with message. I want to add message to this state label /notification message/ on OpenERP client app. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `form` class in the client has a `message_state()` method that displays a message in the status bar. If you look through the `client/bin/modules/gui/window/form.py` file, you can find several calls. I didn't see any easy way to set that message from within a standard module, so you might have to hack the client code.

If you want to display a message from within regular module code, I think you're stuck with a pop-up warning dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Well U can custom message on form with changes in form.mako with understanding of mochikit.